# rsync read from multiple list of files

Tags: rsync

To copy from a list, I can this

```
rsync -av --files-from=/pathtofolder/file1.txt rootdir destdir
```

but what if I have multiples list of files (file1.txt, file2.txt, etc) that has to be rsync'ed. For example none of the wildcard work

```
rsync -av --files-from=/pathtofolder/*.txt rootdir destdir
rsync -av --files-from=/pathtofolder/* rootdir destdir
```

this one works but I have to write every file name

```
rsync -av --files-from=/pathtofolder/{file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt} rooter destdir
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to create virtual file with concatenation of all the files you want to rsync:

```
rsync -av --files-from=<(cat /pathtofolder/*.txt) rootdir destdir
```

Comment: sorry, it does work, I used sync instead rsync that didn't show any error

Comment: You should then accept the answer (check under the vote)